# Inserting multiple Union statements in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building an employee roster capacity table from a roster report where the source data is very challenging. I've managed to build the capability but need some assistance with building a stored procedure that will return multiple columns in the new table: `tbl_Capacity`.

I need to do some update statements after the `INSERT INTO` statement. How do I separate the first 3 columns to add the extra 2 columns that I can then update with an UPDATE statement?

```
Employee    Week_Start  Day1_1  Day1_2      Day1_3  Day2_1  Day2_2  Day2_3
Fred    17/07/2017  0000-0659   0700-1500-X 1501-2359   0000-0659   0700-1500-X 1501-2359
John    17/07/2017  0000-2359   x   x   0000-2359   x   x
```

Desired output:

```
Employee    Date    Roster_Hours    Hours   Available
Fred    17/07/2017  0000-0659   7   1
Fred    17/07/2017  0700-1500-X 8   0
Fred    17/07/2017  1501-2359   9   1
Fred    18/07/2017  0000-0659   7   1
Fred    18/07/2017  0700-1500-X 8   0
John    18/07/2017  1501-2359   9   1
Fred    17/07/2017  0000-2359   24  1
Fred    17/07/2017  x   0   0
Fred    17/07/2017  x   0   0
Fred    18/07/2017  0000-2359   24  1
Fred    18/07/2017  x   0   0
Fred    18/07/2017  x   0   0
```

This is part of the query I've built, the bracket before the first `SELECT` does not work for me.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Capacity
    (SELECT  
         Employee, Week_Start, value
     FROM
         (SELECT Employee, Week_Start, col, value
          FROM [tbl_Rosters]
          CROSS APPLY
              (VALUES ('1', Day1_1),('2', Day1_2),('3', Day1_3)) C (COL, value)) SRC
     WHERE 
         value != 'x'

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         Employee, DATEADD(day, 1, Week_Start), value
     FROM
         (SELECT Employee, Week_Start, col, value
          FROM [tbl_Rosters]
          CROSS APPLY
              (VALUES ('1', Day2_1),('2', Day2_2),('3', Day2_3)) C (COL, value)) SRC
     WHERE value != 'x'), 0, 0

<update statements here>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is with the two extra zeros at the bottom?

Comment: There is a rule in software development that states "test often". This rule is here so that you don't get cases where you type a lot of code and then don't know where to start fixing it. So what you should do is split your query into small parts and test them individually e.g. run the first `SELECT` on its own to see if it works and gives correct results, then do the same for the 2nd one. Then add `UNION ALL` into the mix and so on until you are ready to do the actual insert into another table.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've tested each section and the Union of the Selects works.   The problem I'm having is adding additional columns to the "Insert Into" section.  The 0's are placeholders to then update after the "Insert Into" section.

Comment: @Dave, you need to add 0s into each `select`. e.g. `select Employee, Week_Start, value, 0 AS Hours   , 0 AS Available`

Comment: Thanks Alex, I originally had multiple values but that was copying the format of the first value eg. "Employee, Week_Start, value, value, value"                 that makes sense, I'll give it a go with 0's

Comment: Thanks Alex, I updated the other values with zero's and I got it working with the extra functionality.   I updated the table, rebuilt the SSAS association with this table, rebuilt the Power BI report that integrates with BI Report Server and published it to the Server.  Love how the new version of Power BI can publish to Report Server so users don't need Power BI Desktop to view a Power BI Report!!!  Woo Hoo!!!